# MacVim doesn't load $PATH env variable from .bash_profile

Tags: bash, vim, macvim

When I run MacVim from the command line, it has the environment variable PATH set correctly as I specify in my .bash_profile file.

However, running MacVim from the shortcut has a very stripped down PATH variable, which is making it impossible to use syntastic (it can't find my syntax checker programs).

What is the best way to fix the PATH variable? Can I set it in my .vimrc somehow? Can I make my shortcut load a bash session first or something?

Comment: How do you define your `$PATH`? What is the value of `:set shell` and  `:set shellcmdflag`?

Comment: My .bash_profile has the line `export PATH="/usr/local...:$PATH"`

Comment: For your `$PATH` to work in Vim, you must `:set shellcmdflag=-ic`.